# How do I access my window's files?

Tags: windows, sudo, fdisk

I recently replaced the Windows by Ubuntu and I have any files in my Disc. When I had Windows. How Can I Do to access `$ sudo fdisk -l` to I to recover my disc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only identify which partition it is on and mount it in the location of your choice.

We can use `parted` to identify the partition like so:

```
mgodby@mgodby-UDesk1:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST1000LM014-1EJ1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  1050MB  1049MB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      1050MB  1322MB  273MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, hidden
 3      1322MB  2371MB  1049MB  fat32           Basic data partition          hidden
 4      2371MB  2505MB  134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 5      2505MB  503GB   500GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      503GB   653GB   150GB   ext4                                          msftdata
 8      653GB   936GB   283GB   ext4                                          msftdata
 7      936GB   952GB   16.4GB  linux-swap(v1)
 9      952GB   979GB   26.8GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
10      979GB   1000GB  21.5GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag


Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.
Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label                                  

mgodby@mgodby-UDesk1:~$
```

From the output on my terminal we can make a good guess that the largest ntfs partition, shown here as partition 5 on drive /dev/sda , is my primary Windows partition. Now we just need to mount it up somewhere. For the sake of simplicity, I'll create a directory within my home directory.

1. Create the mount point (can be anywhere,  theoretically, but it's best to choose somewhere under /mnt , /media , or /home/$USER/ . In my example, I'll create a directory called /home/mgodby/windrive to mount it to. `ls -ll` will verify that the directory is indeed present.

   ```
   mgodby@mgodby-UDesk1:~$ mkdir -v /home/mgodby/windrive
   mkdir: created directory ‘/home/mgodby/windrive’
   mgodby@mgodby-UDesk1:~$ ls -ll /home/mgodby | grep windrive
   drwxrwxr-x  2 mgodby mgodby    4096 Oct  8 12:11 windrive
   mgodby@mgodby-UDesk1:~$
   ```
2. Now we just mount the windows partition  in our new directory and verify that everything is there.

   ```
   mgodby@mgodby-UDesk1:~$ sudo mount.ntfs -v /dev/sda5 /home/mgodby/windrive
   mgodby@mgodby-UDesk1:~$ ls -ll /home/mgodby/windrive
   total 19446553
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root        4096 Nov 14  2013 avast! sandbox
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root        8192 Oct 11  2012 Boot
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root      398156 Jul 25  2012 bootmgr
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root           1 Jun 18  2013 BOOTNXT
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root        8192 Oct  9  2012 BOOTSECT.BAK
   -rwxrwxrwx 2 root root        4743 Nov 29  2013 comcastrelease.log
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root           2 Apr  7  2014 END
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6759346176 Oct  7 23:37 hiberfil.sys
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12884901888 Oct  7 23:37 pagefile.sys
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root           0 Aug 22  2013 PerfLogs
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20480 Oct  7 23:51 ProgramData
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20480 Oct  7 23:51 Program Files
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       28672 Oct  7 23:51 Program Files (x86)
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root        4096 Feb  3  2013 PSFONTS
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root        4096 Jan 27  2013 Python33
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root           0 Dec 18  2013 Recovery
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root           0 Jan 19  2014 $Recycle.Bin
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root        4096 Dec  8  2012 Remote Programs
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   268435456 Oct  7 23:38 swapfile.sys
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root        4096 Sep 21 23:22 System Volume Information
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root           0 May  5 15:54 temp
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root           0 Dec  8  2012 UserGuidePDF
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root        4096 Dec 18  2013 Users
   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       28672 Sep 26 17:45 Windows
   mgodby@mgodby-UDesk1:~$
   ```

Now just open that directory and browse your entire Windows partition just like you would any other directory.

EDIT: This process can be used with any other partition on your drive as well. Be sure to use the proper `mount` command according to the partition type, i.e. `mount.fat` for fat32 or `mount.ntfs` for ntfs.